# Destructor not displayed in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

```
#include<iostream>  
#include<conio.h>  
using namespace std;  
class add  
{  
public:  
add()  
{  
    cout<<"Constructor is WORKING"<< endl;  
}  
void disp()  
{  
    cout<<"Function is Working"<< endl;  
}  
~add()  
{  
    cout<<"Destructor is WORKING"<< endl;  
}  
};  
int main()  
{  
add a;  
a.disp();  
getch();  
}
```

I can see the constructor and function.
But, the destructor is not being displayed in visual studio or turbo c++ (I have tried both).
Is there an error in my code? or does it ends without being displayed?

Comment: It gets destructed after getch

Comment: Put a scope around add a; a.disp(); like this `{ add a; a.disp(); }` and see what happens.

Comment: "or turbo c++" - don't even bother with that. It is several decades out of date, doesn't even support standard C++98, it's obsolete and I'd personally consider using it to be actually harmful when trying to learn modern C++ that's actually used in the real world. Drop that thing *now* and don't ever look back.

Comment: Run your program from the console instead of from inside your IDE or by double-clicking it.

Comment: @ClumsyKnight Which version of Visual Studio are you using that you still feel the need of using some input operation (`getch()`) to keep the console open?

Answer (score 3):

The destructor is not called until main exits.  Try doing this:

```
void test()
{
   add a;  
   a.disp();  
}

int main()  
{
   test();
   getch();  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The destructor does output it after `getch`. But you probably do not see that because the window closes.

Change your code to:

```
int main() {  
    {
        add a;  
        a.disp();  
    }
    getch();  
}
```

So that you can see destructor output.

Answer (score 2):

The destructor (not *deconstructor*) will be called at the very end of `main()` function - **after** your `getch()` executes. I assume you call it to make te console wait for your input, instead of closing right away. The problem is - the destructor will be called *after* you press the key, which makes it unlikely for you to spot.

Answer (score -1):

getch() pauses the console until a key is hit and it returns a char for the value of the key pressed.
so i guess that u didnt pressed any key so the main function actually does not ends,therefore a isnt finished its existence >> destructor does not being called.
[You can read about getch() here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio)